# Is it possible to bind two source properties to one control property?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controls

Using WPF, is it possible to bind two source properties, via one-way binding, to one control property (ie textbox.text)??  I'd like to have the user input a value in a textbox and have that value pushed to two different properties in the source datacontext.  My workaround is to create a dummy property and have the setter set the two values manually.

Comment: You're asking two different questions there? Or am I misunderstanding? First you want to use one way binding to your textbox, and then you want to push data back to the source? That's two way...

Comment: I think he wants to bind the textbox.text to two distinct binding sources, s.th.a change in the textbox will change both their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use kind of binding-proxy, as described in this blog post:

http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-properties

Then just follow these steps for example:

1. Define a TextBox with x:Name=tb
2. Bind TextBox.Text to Prop1
3. Add a Proxy-Element with In="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb}", Out="{Binding Prop2}" (not within but beside the TextBox)

This way, you will have Prop1 and Prop2 synchronized with tb.Text.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx). See the example in the documentation