# How can I add a calculated additional column in WPF DataGrid / ListView / ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a `DataGrid` and a View Model (`MyViewModel1`). The `DataGrid` is bound to the Items property of `MyViewModel1`. The constraint is that I can not touch the code of `MyViewModel1` and `MyClass1`.

```
public class MyViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass1> Items { get { ... } }
    public int ViewModelProperty1 { get { ... } }
    public int ViewModelProperty2 { get { ... } }
}

public class MyClass1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public int Property1 { get { ... } }
    public int Property2 { get { ... } }
    public int Property3 { get { ... } }
}
```

I would like the `DataGrid` to show not just 3 columns with the 3 known properties, but also a 4th column on each row, which is dependent on `Property1`, `Property2`, `Property3`, `ViewModelProperty1` and `ViewModelProperty2`. For the sake of the example let's say the 4th column is `Property1 + Property2 + Property3 + ViewModelProperty1 + ViewModelProperty2`. The 4th column must show the current value, so if `ViewModelProperty1` is increased by one, the 4th column must also be increased by one. My question is: What are my options to do this?

I can think of these:

1. Use an `IMultiValueConverter` with all dependent variables as inputs. This works well for the example. The issue here is that as soon as the interaction of the variables becomes more complex e.g. `((Property1 + 2*Property2) * Property3) ^ (ViewModelProperty1 - ViewModelProperty2)`, the order in which the 5 variables are put in the 'MultiBinding' becomes important and there is a lot of knowledge in the binding which can cause the the solution to become brittle.
2. Use a wrapper. Bind the `DataGrid` to a new class `MyViewModel2`, which registers to changes on `MyViewModel1`, and looks something like

   ```
   public class MyViewModel2
   {
       public MyViewModel2(MyViewModel1 m) { ... }
       ...
       public ObservableCollection<MyClass2> Items { get { ... } }
   }
   public class MyClass2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public MyClass2(MyClass1 inner)
       {
           InnerClass = inner;
           InnerClass.NotifyPropertyChanged += InnerClassChanged;
       }
       void InnerClassChanged(object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged("Property4");
       }
       public void ViewModelPropertiesChanged
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged("Property4");
       }

       public MyClass1 InnerClass { get; private set; }
       public int Property4
       {
           get { return InnerClass.Property1+InnerClass.Property2 ... }
       }
       public event PropertyChanged;
   }
   ```

The question is what ways exist to solve this problem in addition to the 2 I mentioned above (Converter and Wrapper).

My question is not which way is the best way to solve the example.

Comment: There really aren't any other ways that are clean (ex: you could put the combined data fields in the code-behind). However, it's worth noting that it is possible for your multiple value converter to call out to another object to perform the value translation. This could make it less "brittle" by taking potential business logic back into some shared class.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just saw that you already thought of this! Not that I understand your objection.

You could use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx). See the example in the IMultiValueConverter documentation.

(From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2002598/360211)

Comment: Thanks for the response. To give more background info, I've ran into this problem quite a few times in the past and in the real world cases I'm dealing with there are sometimes more, sometimes less than the 5 dependencies this example has. In one case I had 15 dependent variables spread over 3 classes, and there the 'MultiBinding' approach becomes impractical. Where exactly that point is is subjective. For the cases with 2-3 variables I often end up using a 'MultiBinding'.
It would be great if there'd be some way similar to extension methods, or something with attached properties.

Comment: It sounds like your viewmodels are too far from removed from the view. The viewmodel should represent the data that is displayed in the view. Some light formatting, simple arithmetic are OK to have in the `xaml`, but complex calculations with 15 variables tells me something major is missing from the view model. Why can't you touch the view models themselves?

Comment: There's a balance between sharing the same 'ViewModel' for similar 'Views's versus having one 'ViewModel' per 'View'. I found that there are projects where having one 'ViewModel' per 'View' is too heavy on maintenance, and that it's usually better to have a well designed view model shared among multiple views, using simple 'IValueConverter' and 'IMultiValueConverter' classes to make up for the differences.
The 15 variables case did result in an additional 'ViewModel' (Wrapper), but I'm looking if there are other solutions where neither 'MultiBinding' nor an extra 'ViewModel' are a perfect fit.